# Making a Raspberry Pi Into a Audio Streamer that Connects to Apple Airplay

Tags: raspbian, audio, pulseaudio, mopidy

first time on these forums. I have been looking all day and couldn't find anything related to it or have but no one posted back if they succeed or not.

I found the same topic here, but it was hard to understand and not sure if it was tailored to my problem.

The Objective:

I have a Crestron Amplifier that is capable of AirPlay & spotify. To use spotify you would need to use premium and the native app to connect to it (spotify Connect).

OPTION 1: I want to use a raspberry Pi to behave like a phone in ways that it can select the Crestron Amplifier as an Airplay device and run music VIA spotify using the airplay method and not the spotify connect. Prefer Option

OPTION 2: I was thinking about using the Raspberry Pi as the actually receiver and wired it into the amplifier and just have the devices (Iphone. laptops) connect to it VIA spotify Connect.

I heard the combination of PluseAudio & Mopidy can work, as Mopidy is having the interface of spotify and PluseAudio to re direct the music into the sink (the crestron amplifier).

If this is a duplicate I am terribly sorry, as I mentioned above I tried looking for it. If it is just let me know if this is the right method.

Cheers.